# JSON grab value from nested data structure

Tags: javascript, json, express

So i've seen this asked a few times by what i'm getting back is a little different.

So i'm within a route in express and i'm trying to get a value I send. So I `res.send(data)` and my data looks like this :

```
{

   "StatusCode": 200,

   "Payload": {

      "ETag": "\"f8743837473874h\"",

      "Location": "http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/image_holding%2Fcreated_images/b13_zmb0kuklvaaxvkzqhnh7protgcg51e_q1_image_w17.png",

      "key": "b13_zmb0kuklvaaxvkzqhnh7protgcg51e_q1_image_w17.png"

   }

}
```

so I want to trigger a file download on the url i'm sending across.

However, I can't access it like I thought. I've been trying `data.Payload` which gives me back everything in `Payload` but I can't access anything within. I've tried `data.Payload[0].Location` and `data.Payload.Location` but I can't seem to access the `Location` field.

Comment: What form does the data take on the client? What does `console.log(typeof data);` say?

Comment: `data.Payload.Location` works on fiddle, are you missing anything else? Perhaps not in the shown code?

Comment: I'm not handling it on the client because i'm trying to force the download of a file I need to handle it on the server so within my `app.post` request when I send across the `data` i'm trying to start a file downlaod as well